# Wait for nested iframes to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a script tag that dynamically loads an iframe. That iframe has it's own script tags that load another iframe inside the first one. (Stupid I know but I can't control the plugin).

I need to do the following:
- Wait for the first iframe to be dynamically created
- Wait for the iframe's script to execute and load the nested iframe
- Get the body height of the nested iframe

I've tried listening for DOM changes at both levels with no luck. The following gets the first iframe but not the second. There must be an easier way!

```
// init
  // --------------------------------

  // define mutation observer
  MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

  // wait for document ready
  $(document).on('ready', iframeDimensionsFaq);


  // iframe dimensions function
  // --------------------------------

  function iframeDimensionsFaq() {

    // get iframe parent element
    var parent = document.getElementById('helpjuice_js_widget_content');

    // observe iframe parent for DOM changes
    observe(parent, function(firstIframe){

      firstIframe.addEventListener('load', function() {

        // observe second iframe
        observe(this, function(secondIframe){
          console.log(secondIframe);
        });

      });

    });

  };


  // observe element for new nodes
  // --------------------------------

  function observe(el, cb) {

    // create new mutation observer
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {

      // check for added nodes
      if (!mutations[0].addedNodes) return;

      // loop added nodes & check for iframe
      var addedNodes = mutations[0].addedNodes;
      for (var i=0; i<addedNodes.length; i++) {
        if (addedNodes[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'iframe') {
          cb(addedNodes[i]);
        }
      }

    });

    // observe parent for DOM changes
    observer.observe(el, {
      subtree: false,
      attributes: true,
      childList: true
    });

  };
```